# How to create a visual showing top 3 employees with highest sales for every date in a bar chart?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with the Date, Analyst Name, and Quantity of tickets resolved. What I want to create is a visual with a stacked bar chart for every date showing the top 3 analysts with the highest quantities of tickets resolved for each day.

I have tried using the TOP N filter but it filters every analyst except the 3 with the highest number of tickets resolved overall. But I want for each date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a rank measure.
Considering the following table with sample data:

| Date | Analyst Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 5 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 15 |
| 2021-01-01 | D | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 42 |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 32 |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 22 |
| 2021-01-02 | D | 12 |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 15 |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 5 |
| 2021-01-03 | C | 21 |
| 2021-01-03 | D | 30 |

You can write a measure like this:

```
Rank =
RANKX (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        'Table',
        -- remove the filter an Analyst Name to only keep grouping by Date
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Table'[Analyst Name] )
    ),
    -- CALCULATE needed here for context transition
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Quantity] )
    )
)
```

In your report just pull this measure into the filter panel and configure it like this:

[image: Measure in filter pane]

The result will then look like this:

[image: Resulting visual]